# An elegant closure property of uniform distributions?

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, ring-homomorphism, polynomial-rings, morphism

- In [dice notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice_notation), any collection of polyhedral dice can be represented as a polynomial in one unknown. For example, $1d^{20} + 3d^6$ denotes a collection consisting of one 20-sided die and three 6-sided dice.
- There is a map $P$ sending any such collection of dice to the corresponding probability distribution. For example, the map sends the single $k$-sided die $d^k$ to the uniform distribution $U_k$ over $1\ldots k$.
- In general, you compute the distribution of a sum of dice by taking the convolution of the individual dice distributions. For example, the map $P$ sends $d^a + 3d^b$ to $U_a\oplus (U_b \oplus U_b \oplus U_b)$.
- In this way, the map $P$ is a morphism between the space of dice polynomials (formalized as a polynomial rig) and the space of dice probabilities (formalized as the set of all the uniform distributions $U_1, U_2, U_3,\ldots$, plus all finite convolutions of them).

  It preserves addition, sending polynomial sums to probability convolutions.
- But polynomials also have *multiplicative* structure: The product of two individual dice $d^a\cdot d^b$ is $d^{a+b}$, for example, and the corresponding distribution is $U_{a+b}$.
- **My question:** Can we define multiplication on the target space of distributions so that $P$ preserves multiplication as well as addition, acting as a kind of ring homomorphism?

  We already know what the multiplication operator must be on the uniform distributions $U_k$; we have $U_a \otimes U_b \equiv U_{a+b}$.

  I *think* that if we impose the distributive property along with this base case, we have enough to define $\otimes$ throughout the entire space. Indeed if $A$ and $B$ are finite convolutions of $U_i$, then $A\otimes B$ can be expanded according to the distributive property into a unique convolution of uniform distributions $U_j$.

  But I am unsure how to prove whether this works---is the operator really well defined, or does it somehow give contradictory or underdetermined answers in some cases?

Comment: Seems like this operator must lose a lot of information about the two distributions -- what if we had $(U_m+n) \otimes U_k$ -- would the resulting distribution continue to be $U_{m+n}$?

Comment: The operator $\otimes$ is defined on uniform distributions $U_k$ over $1\ldots k$ by $U_m\otimes U_n = U_{m+n}$, and on finite convolutions of these specific uniform distributions by the distributive property for $(U_a\oplus U_b)\otimes(U_c\oplus U_d)$.  It is not defined anywhere else. I'm wondering if this operator, as stated, is well-defined or if it somehow gives conflicting answers.

Comment: Ah, ok -- because this threw me off "Can the space of discrete distributions be given such an algebraic structure?" That's a lot broader than the discrete uniform anchored at $0$.

Comment: @Bey Ok, that makes sense. I've updated the text of the question to clarify the spaces. Thanks!